# After scrolling in the listview, elements are swapped

Tags: java, android, listview

I writing time-tracking app, every row of listview has two buttons(Start and Stop) and some textView to display elapsed time.

After scrolling in the listview, elements are swapped.

I'm not sure in my solution, but i put in the model class, ViewHolder object for getting acces for changing view elements.

Here is the fragment of code model

```
private String name;
private  Boolean isStart=false;
private  Long elapsedTime=0L,seconds=0L,hours=0L,minutes=0L,lastPause=0L,updateTime=0L,startTime=0L,days=0L;
private Runnable updateTimeThread=new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if(isStart && startTime!=0) {
        updateTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + lastPause);
        seconds = updateTime / 1000;
        minutes = seconds / 60;
        hours = minutes / 60;

        seconds = seconds % 60;
        minutes = minutes % 60;
        hours = hours % 24;

        holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d", days));
        holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
        holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
        holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));
        Log.d("myTag",name+" "+seconds);
        MainActivity.handler.post(this);
    }
}
             };

MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder;

    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder getHolder() {
return holder;
  }

   public void setHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder) {
    this.holder = holder;
   }

     public Runnable getRunnable() {
return updateTimeThread;
         }
```

Adapter's fragment code

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
final Runnable updateTimeThread=tracker.getRunnable();


View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
ViewHolder holder;

if(row == null){
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
    holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
    holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
    holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
    holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
    holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
    row.setTag(holder);
}else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
}
    holder.start.setEnabled(true);
    holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
    holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;



if(tracker.getIsStart()){
    holder.start.setEnabled(false);
    holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
}


 onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.btStart:
                 tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                 tracker.setIsStart(true);
                 tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                 MainActivity.handler.post(updateTimeThread);
                 finalHolder.start.setEnabled(false);
                 finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                 break;
             case R.id.btStop:
                 tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                 MainActivity.handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeThread);
                 finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                 finalHolder.start.setEnabled(true);
                 tracker.setIsStart(false);
                 break;
         }
     }
 };
holder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
holder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
return row;
 }

static class ViewHolder{
TextView  name,days,hours,minutes,seconds;
Button start,stop;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add these two methods to my adapter)

```
  @Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

**UPDATE**
But with Loader Callback problem is still the same. I press Start on last item and scroll down, values not visible, scroll up a bit and values visible. Pity.

**UPDATE 2** This article solve my problem, i just change layout-height and laoyut-weight from "wrap_content" to "fill_parent" to avoid multiple calling getView() method. 
http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/06/tips-for-listview-view-recycling-use.html

Answer (score 0):

Change this part

```
holder.start.setEnabled(true);
holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;

if(tracker.getIsStart()){
holder.start.setEnabled(false);
holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
}
```

to this

```
final ViewHolder finalholfder = holder;

finalholfder.start.setEnabled(true);
finalholfder.stop.setEnabled(false);
finalholfder.name.setText(tracker.getName());


if(tracker.getIsStart()){
finalholfder.start.setEnabled(false);
finalholfder.stop.setEnabled(true);
} else{
finalholfder.start.setEnabled(true);
finalholfder.stop.setEnabled(false);
}
```

And this

```
holder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);  
holder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

to this

```
 finalholfder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
 finalholfder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can't understand how it link with swapped elements in listview, i changed my code but problem is still the same

Comment: on every scroll getview will change convertview, I faced this problem alot. and I fixed it like this only, for every if statement I wrote counter else statment and used finalviewholder for each position.

Comment: I tested again, but it didn't work for me, if i start the first timer and scroll to last, last item will swapped with first (just value). Its just one of replacing.